# Python implementation of the 24 game

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, performance, refactoring

Below is my attempt to implement the 24 game in Python 2, I tried to follow the requirements specified from leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/24-game/description/

My approach is basically check all the permutations of the 4 provided numbers against all the permutations of 3 operations out of 4 (add, subtract, multiply and divide).

I used `iteratools.product()` to get the permutations of the operations because there could be repeated operations.

I have two questions:

1. I am not sure if the 3 blocks of code inside my inner for loop cover all the cases, if it does, how can I prove that? For instance, I am not sure if I should check `((W op (X op Y) op Z))` or not.
2. I think in the worst case there would be 24 * 64 * 9 = 13824 calculations. Can the number of calculations be reduced?

---

```
import itertools
class Solution(object):
    def judgePoint24(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: bool
        """
        Ops = list(itertools.product([add,sub,mul,div], repeat=3))
        for ns in set(itertools.permutations(nums)):
            for ops in Ops:
                # W = ns[0], X = ns[1], Y = ns[2], Z = ns[3]

                # (((W op X) op Y) op Z)
                result = ops[0](ns[0], ns[1])
                result = ops[1](result, ns[2])
                result = ops[2](result, ns[3])
                if 23.99 < result < 24.01:
                    return True

                # (Z op (Y op (W op X)))
                result = ops[0](ns[0], ns[1])
                result = ops[1](ns[2], result)
                result = ops[2](ns[3], result)
                if 23.99 < result < 24.01:
                    return True

                # ((W op X) op (Y op Z))
                result1 = ops[0](ns[0], ns[1])
                result2 = ops[1](ns[2], ns[3])
                result = ops[2](result1, result2)
                if 23.99 < result < 24.01:
                    return True
        return False

def add (a, b):
    return a+b
def sub (a, b):
    return a-b
def mul (a, b):
    return a*b
def div (a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 0
    return a/float(b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some general pointers.

1. You can [cache](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) the result of some computations. This is probably not required in your case, but you should know how to trade off memory vs. time.
2. You can avoid repeated calculations (the expression `ops[0](ns[0], ns[1])` is evaluated three times in every iteration). Get the result once and insert it in further expressions.
3. The last point leads to a more general consideration: each expression can be represented as a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree). Right now you're brute-forcing all possible trees in an (almost) random order. Is there a way to do it in a "smarter" order? Sure! If the first two numbers are `9` and `9`, and you are at `9*9+(x op y)`, then it doesn't matter which operation you pick and what the remaining two numbers are - you will not be able to get down to 24. Try to think of more "stop conditions" when you don't need to continue evaluating.